# SSRS Report from two SharePoint Lists Error

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2013

I have two SharePoint lists that I need to retrieve data from for one report.  The fields in common is "Request ID" in the main table (Action Items) and "ID" in the table (Requests) with the field that I need (Application).  I've tried using this approach that I found in a solution:

```
=Join(
      LookupSet(
                Fields!FirstList_Key.Value, 
                Fields!SecondList_Key.Value, 
                Fields!SecondList_DisplayCol.Value, 
                "Name of Second List")
      )
```

Here is what my code actually says:
    =Join(LookupSet(Fields!Request_ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value,     Fields!Application.Value, "Requests"))

[image: Datasets]

But I continue to get an error "The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox4.." contains an error.  Request for the permission type of 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission...' failed.

I have no idea what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for some reason, I had to cast both the key values as Int.

=Join(LookupSet(Cint(Fields!Request_ID.Value), CInt(Fields!ID.Value), Fields!Application.Value, "Requests"), ", ")

This works...